# Constructing a Wordpress Permalink?

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

Replacement of a poorly worded, (deleted) question from yesterday.

I have a pre-built website that needs Wordpress added to it consisting of two pages.

1. Paginated list of blog posts, 5 per page, (with excerpts). Using the post title as the link to full post.
2. Full post permalink, (clicked through from page one).

I have part one done and working using the following loop..

```
<?php 
      $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

      $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'paged' => $paged,
      );

      $loop = new WP_Query( $args );                    

      if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
 ?>

          <!-- Display the Title as a link to the Post's permalink. -->
          <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

          <!-- Display the date and a link to other posts by this posts author.-->
          <small><?php the_time('F jS, Y'); ?> by <?php the_author(); ?></small>

          <!-- Display the Post as Excerpt. -->
          <div class="blogpost">
            <?php the_excerpt($more_link_text); ?>
          </div>

          <hr>

 <?php
       endwhile;

       $pagetotal = $loop->max_num_pages;

       if ($pagetotal > 1){

         $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));

         echo paginate_links(array(
          'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
          'format' => 'page/%#%',
          'current' => $current_page,
          'total' => $pagetotal,
          'prev_text'    => __('« prev'),
          'next_text'    => __('next »'),
           ));
       }    
    }
    wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

The above works great, including the pagination aspect, I am now however stuck as to what I need to do to with this code to get the Permalinks to display as just the full post, (currently it just reloads the loop list).

**I assume that both the list page and the permalink page use index.php?**

Permalinks are set up as http://www.mywebsite.com/blog/this-is-a-post in Wordpress setting and the relevant .htaccess is up.

Thanks in advance for any light or links shed on this..

Answer (score 0):

When you say you want to display the "Permalink page", are you just referring to displaying the full blog post, no listing? If so, you'll need to create a file called single.php and include the Loop (minimally).

```
if (have_posts()) :
   while (have_posts()) :
      the_post();
         the_content();
   endwhile;
endif;
```

You can get more information on creating this file and how it impacts the display of your content here:

https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop_in_Action#Different_Single_Post_Format

Comment: Just to clarify, I have put all the WP files in a folder on the site called blog and re-written index.php to match the sites existing css etc. but added the loop code to the main body of that page to loop through and paginate the blog posts. 

(I've set `define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);` so I don't use any WP themes) -Will the single.php file I write become the source for the permalink? 

Also, Thanks for the response. Much appreciated.

Comment: So you edited the root index.php file of WordPress? That's probably not what you want to do, if I'm understanding correctly.